# unathorized access - SIGSEGV C

Tags: segmentation-fault

My programm throws SIGSEG error.
When i run it in VisualStudio it works fine but when i run it on our school linux server it throws SIGSEG. Have you guys any ideas? Code is here:

```
         struct obj_t {
            int id;
            float x;
            float y;
        };

        struct cluster_t {
            int size;
            int capacity;
            struct obj_t *obj;
        };

    int load_clusters(char *filename, struct cluster_t **arr)
    {
        assert(arr != NULL);
        FILE *sub;
        int pocet;  

        sub=fopen(filename,"r");
        fscanf(sub,"%*[^0123456789]%d",&pocet);

        arr[0]=(cluster_t*) malloc(pocet*sizeof(cluster_t));

        for(int i=0 ; i<pocet ; i++){

            arr[0][i].obj=(obj_t*)malloc(sizeof(obj_t));
            fscanf(sub,"%*[^.0123456789]%d%*[^.0123456789]%f%*[^.0123456789]%f",&arr[0][i].obj->id,&arr[0][i].obj->x,&arr[0][i].obj->y);
            arr[0][i].capacity=1;
            arr[0][i].size=1;

        }

        fclose(sub);
        return pocet;
    }
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct cluster_t *clusters;

    int a=load_clusters("soubor.txt",&clusters);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the error will be somewhere around malloc but i'm not sure and i cant debbug it step by step in that linux server.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know what a [segmentation fault](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj) is? It is most likely caused by an array index out of bounds here. Check the sizes of your arrays and the indexes you are using.

Comment: more info: The headers of functions are given and i can't change them.

Comment: Function headers can't seg-fault.

Comment: Yes, i wrote that in case of somebody would like to change them. I checked the code and i dont know where i access some undeclared memory.

Comment: I mam not a C expert but I think you need a main function. What headers you are talking of? You did not includ any header. Rhat warnings are displayed when you compile the program?